# Tensorflow RNN simple and easy examples/ templates for fitting curves?

Tags: python, tensorflow, curve-fitting, recurrent-neural-network

I am looking for simple and easy examples or template scripts of Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) with Tensorflow, applicabel to my problem. I am trying to fit a curve trough noisy data x, with the additional challenge that the data has a gap (see figure below) - in that sense I am trying to predict x inside and outside the gap.

More about my problem and data: Beside x, I also have as data the time and 2 other features, which are partially influencing the behavior of x. So, I have as potential input 690 data vectors, each vector with a length of 4 features (time, x and 2 other features). For time=[340,580] there is only a gap in x, but not in the 2 other features.

Have you encountered some simple codes that I can easily modify for my problem? Have you done some ML/AI-networks tutorials, that were using code applicable to my problem? 
[image]

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data used in the scatterplot?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I edited my post and included a link to the data, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an OK fit to the equation "x = a*pow(ln(time+b),c)" with the parameters a = 6.6758288202172349E+04, b = 6.0783313776716161E+00, and c = 1.6826967379067199E-02 with R-squared = 0.90 and RMSE = 82.3 (see graph).

[image: modelplot]

Comment: The data has already been fitted with numerical approaches. Want I want to achieve now is really to fit the data with a machine learning code, so that I can compare to the performance of numerical fits (like the one that you present). Among others, I have to check if there is maybe some hidden small structure in the data, that deviates from the completely smooth curve. Therefore, can you give me some suitable recurrent neural network template?

Comment: To answer your question, I personally have not worked with neural networks for some time and have no template code.

Comment: It still helps, tnx! But why is there a coma-sign in your equation "x = a*pow(ln(time+b),c)". Sorry, I don't quite understand the syntax. And what program/script did you use to make the fit?

Comment: In many computing languages power function syntax take two parameters, such as power(a,b) with the comma used as a separator. To answer your question on making the fit, I performed equation search with my open source curve and surface fitting web site zunzun.com - it uses a genetic algorithm named Differential Evolution to determine initial parameter estimates for non-linear equations and has a "function finder" for equation search.

Comment: I see now, thanks! So in python syntax I would be "x=a*(ln(time+b))**c" or in wolframalpha syntax "x=a*(ln(time+b))^c". I will play around at zunzun.com to check for other stuff it might help me :)